# How can I use a Linux box's display as a third display for my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, unix

At work, I have a MacBook Pro that I use as my primary machine. I also have a RHEL6 box that has a dual-head graphics card. When my KVM is switched to the Mac, the second display that is hooked to the Linux box is not being used.

I know there is software the enable other computers to act as displays over a network without an additional physical display connection. Is there software that supports a Linux workstation being the third display for my Mac?

Comment: I haven't done the research to see if AirDisplay or Screen Recycler work with a linux client. See here for more http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36196/is-there-software-that-allows-me-to-use-my-macbook-pro-as-a-second-monitor-for-i

Comment: I use AirDisplay for my iPad right now and ScreenRecycler I've heard of before and that worked well. Will research more about Linux support.

Comment: I went ahead and accepted @mjturner's answer since it actually is a good alternative solution. I'm instead using the linux box as a secondary viewer of things like a browser so it works for my purposes until something better comes along.

Comment: @mjturner's does not answer your question. You accept answers that are correct, not the ones you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if it'll meet your needs, but [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) works very well as a software KVM and it supports any mix of OS X, Linux and Windows.

Comment: Not exactly related to the question, but it seems like pretty cool software none the less.

Comment: Yeah, I've been using Synergy for a while. It is very cool software, but not what I'm looking for here.

Comment: Hi @KyleHayes, did you find an answer to your question? Does Synergy do what you were trying to?