# Use MacBook Pro as second monitor for iMac?

Tags: display, screen, dual-screen

Is it possible to use a MacBook Pro as a second monitor for my iMac? Both of them have a Thunderbolt port.

If not, is there any other way?

Answer (score 9):

You can not use your MacBook Pro as a second monitor for your iMac without additional software.

[ScreenRecycler](http://www.screenrecycler.com/ScreenRecycler.html) claims to allow you to expand your desktop across multiple computers.

[image: Screen shot from ScreenRecycler website]

As an alternative approach, [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy) (previously open source at [synergy-foss.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20130430150437/http://synergy-foss.org/)) claims to [lets you combine multiple computers](http://lifehacker.com/254648/how-to-control-multiple-computers-with-a-single-keyboard-and-mouse) into one. It will let you use both computers from a single keyboard and mouse.

[image: Synergy]

Comment: "ScreenRecycler is currently not compatible with OSX 10.11 or later." https://www.screenrecycler.com/download.html, Are there any alternatives now?

Comment: Synergy does not appear to be open source, you have to purchase it.

Comment: @jzadra it appears the developers have made Synergy a commercial product. The answer's [Synergy link](https://web.archive.org/web/20130430150437/http://synergy-foss.org/) now points to the Internet Archive.

Answer (score 2):

For newer computers with Retina Displays and macOS 10.14+, the best way to use another Mac, iPad, AppleTV, etc. as a separate monitor is with AirPlay. See [Mirror or extend your Mac display](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204289#mirrormac)

Alternatively, (and separate from the original question) if you have an iPad Pro or an iPad Air, you can try using [Sidecar](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210380)

Answer (score 1):

For modern Macbooks there's a feature called Universal Control which let's you connect to any other Macbook / Apple device and control it using a single mouse and keyboard, you just have to sign into both of them using your iCloud account.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212757

Answer (score -1):

**Apple Target Display** (Thunderbolt method)

- Make sure both computers are turned on and awake.
- Connect a male-to-male Mini DisplayPort or ThunderBolt cable to each computer.
- Press <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> on the keyboard of the iMac being used as a display to enable TDM.

Check this link before:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592

Comment: iMac as second monitor, not Macbook Pro as second monitor.