# How to use an old MacBook Pro as a display?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, dual-screen

I have 2 MacBooks:

1. MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)
2. MacBook Pro (13-inch, Late 2011)

I want to use the old MacBook as a display. How? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Target Display Mode doesn't work on MacBook Pros. However, this [thread here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110054/can-i-use-my-macbook-pro-retina-as-extra-monitor-for-my-imac-through-thunderbolt) describes various ways to use the MacBook Pro as a screen. In a nutshell, it says to use a third party app such as Air Display or Screen Recycler (both of which, it appears, operate over a network. The thread suggests connecting the two computers with a thunderbolt cable and thunderbolt network to speed up the connection. For more details, see the link above.

Comment: Although honestly those are pretty difficult solutions. I would suggest selling the old MBP and buying an external screen. It'll be cheaper and easier.

Comment: I agree with Noah's comment. If you don't have a need for the older MacBook, sell it and use some of the money for an external display. If you do still need it otherwise, just buy a cheap external display. Either way, that's a much better solution.